# Sum $\sum _{k=0}^{\infty } \frac{(-z)^k}{\text{IteratedLog}(k+2)}$

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

The following result can be obtained by means of succession acceleration. Can this result also be calculated in Mathematica?

$$\sum _{k=0}^{\infty } \frac{(-z)^k}{\text{IteratedLog}(k+2)}=\frac{z+2}{2 (z+1)}$$

Note that the iterated logarithm can be found as a [resource function](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/IteratedLog).

Comment: I assume that you've already tried to simply use `Series`. Can you show the code you've tried and what result you obtained?

Comment: The command `ResourceFunction["IteratedLog"][x]` hardly interacts with other Mathematica commands. Foe example, `DiscreteLimit[
 ResourceFunction["IteratedLog"][i + 1]/
  ResourceFunction["IteratedLog"][i], i -> Infinity]` returns the input. Ask your question at [this forum](https://tetrationforum.org/forumdisplay.php?fid=3).

Comment: This is math, not Mathematica. I voted to close the question.

Answer (score 5):

Your proposed answer is wrong. Let

$$
q_0=1\\
q_1=\lfloor e \rfloor=2\\
q_2=\lfloor e^e \rfloor=15\\
q_3=\lfloor e^{e^e} \rfloor=3814279\\
\cdots
$$

([OEIS A056072](https://oeis.org/A056072)),
so that your sum becomes

$$
\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-z)^k}{\text{IteratedLog}(k+2)}
= \frac11\sum_{k=0}^0 (-z)^k
+ \frac12\sum_{k=1}^{13} (-z)^k
+ \frac13\sum_{k=14}^{3814277} (-z)^k
+\cdots\\
= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=q_{n-1}-1}^{q_n-2}(-z)^k\\
= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-z)^{q_{n-1}-1}-(-z)^{q_n-1}}{n(1+z)}\\
=\frac{1}{1+z}\left[1-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-z)^{q_n-1}}{n(n+1)}\right]\\
=\frac{1}{1+z}\left[1+\frac{z}{2}-\frac{z^{14}}{6}-\frac{z^{3814278}}{12}-\cdots\right]\\
$$
You only captured the first two terms in the bracket, but there are infinitely many.

Some Mathematica code:

```
q[n_] := Floor[Nest[Exp, 1, n]]
Table[q[n], {n, 0, 3}]
(*    {1, 2, 15, 3814279}    *)

(1 - Sum[(-z)^(q[n] - 1)/(n (n + 1)), {n, 3}]) / (1 + z)
(*    (1 + z/2 - z^14/6 - z^3814278/12) / (1 + z)    *)
```

Check by explicit construction:

```
f[z_] = Sum[(-z)^k/ResourceFunction["IteratedLog"][k + 2], {k, 0, 100}];
Series[(1 + z) f[z], {z, 0, 100}]
(*    1 + z/2 - z^14/6 + O[z]^101    *)
```

Note that $q$ increases very rapidly, and $q_4\approx 2.331504399007195\times 10^{1656520}$ already cannot be used for computer-sized calculations.

Comment: +1. A nice work.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to demonstrate that the statement is not true is as follows. First,  the series `s=Sum[(-1/2)^k/ResourceFunction["IteratedLog"][k + 2], {k, 0, Infinity}]` converges. This follows from `ResourceFunction["IteratedLog"][k + 2] > 1` for  `k > 13` and `RealAbs[s] <= Sum[2^-k,{k,0,Infinity}]+Sum[(1/2)^k/ResourceFunction["IteratedLog"][k + 2], {k, 0,13}]`. Second,

```
s10^4=Sum[(-1/2)^k/ResourceFunction["IteratedLog"][k + 2], {k, 0, 10^4}] //N
```

> `0.833327`

The series under consideration is [an alternating series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series), so the error between `s` and `s10^4` is less than `2^(-10^3)==9.33264*10^-302` (`2^(-10^4)` is too small.). Third,

```
N[(z + 2)/2/(z + 1) /. z -> 1/2]
```

> `0.833333`

Summarizing the above, we can draw the conclusion that the statement of the question is false for `z==1/2`.

Edit. `2^(-10^3)`instead of `2^-10` and  `z -> 1/2` instead of `z->-1/2`.